# Can 2D transpose convolution be represented as a Toeplitz matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrix, transpose, convolution, deconvolution, toeplitz

Can a 2D transpose convolution operation be represented as a matrix multiplication with the Toeplitz matrix, as can be done for a normal convolution?

I want to generalise some ideas from a dense network to a convolutional network. For normal convolutions, this is not a problem, as they can be represented as matrix multiplications with the Toeplitz matrix. But I couldn't find a clear mathematical formulation of transposed convolution, so I am not sure about this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a mathematical answer, so should have probably asked somewhere else, anyways I think my latex write-up is correct and answers the question:

[formula transposed convolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r88B0.png)